# Shell_exec PHP for Android ADB

Tags: php, adb, exec

Ive created a little php script to remote execute Adb for android. This following part works fine:

```
<?php
    $cmd = 'c:/Data/adb.exe "reboot"';
    shell_exec("$cmd");
?>
```

But when i try to change the argument "reboot" for this:

shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS

It doenst execute the script anymore, i think its because of the white spaces? Becaus every string without whitespace does work fine.

Can anybody help me out with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It is better not to *describe* the changes you do but rather post your code after the change

Comment: Can you just try `$cmd = 'c:/Data/adb.exe shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS'`? (Note: no double quotes)